# Return information about existing data SQLite

Tags: c++, sql, c, database, sqlite

I want to have information if data exists or not.
Here is a sample:

```
if("SELECT ORDER_STATUS FROM REPAIR WHERE ORDER_STATUS = 'Waiting for client'" != NULL) {
   printf("\nNotification:");
   printf("\nThere are unclaimed cars.");}
```

I know that it doesn't work. SQL commands don't return NULL in this situation. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Use Count  SELECT COUNT(ORDER_STATUS) As Counter FROM REPAIR WHERE ORDER_STATUS = 'Waiting for client'"

Comment: Did you search the web : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm?

Comment: Your "query" is currently just a C-string. you should probably have a query object somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @RajatJaiswal. I've used your idea and changed some lines in callback and it works.

Comment: You are welcome @PyQ